# PHP - Symfony2 Functional Testing HTTPS Routes

Tags: php, symfony, testing, https, functional-programming

I have defined an HTTPS route in Symfony2 using schemas: (YAML below)

```
login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: RESTAPI:Login:login }
    methods: [POST]
    schemes:  [https]
```

And now I wish to perform functional tests on that very route,

(My test class derives from WebTestCase)

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/login');
$response = $client->getResponse();
```

I seem to always get a RedirectResponse from Symfony instead of my real Controller's response, since Symfony returns a redirection response when trying to access an HTTPS route using HTTP.

How can I solve this problem and test my route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've accidentally encountered this:

In order to simulate an HTTPS request, you simply have to set ['HTTPS' => true] in the $server parameter of $client->request();

Example:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/login', [], [], ['HTTPS' => true]);
```